What thickness and dimensions aluminum or steel plate will support 1,763.6 lbs on a flat surface?
I'm planning on getting base plates made of aluminium or stainless steel to support a shelf.
The shelf's total weight will be around 800 kg or 1,763 lbs. The shelf is an industrial storage rack. The legs have dimensions of 6 cm wide and 6 cm long in the shape of a square. (2,3 inches)
There are 4 legs. The shelf is 60 cm wide, 195 cm long.
The legs will rest on a flat surface.
How thick and in what dimensions should these base plates be in so that they will not bend?

How many legs? 2, 4 or 24? what spacing?

There are 4 legs in total. The shelf is 60 cm wide. The space between the legs is 48 cm.

What are the base plates gong to be sitting on, concrete, a wooden floor?
